# authenticate throw squid proxy (PHP socket)

Tags: php, sockets, squid

I'd like to create a program which could authenticate throw Squid proxy. 
I'm using socket in PHP langage

Answer (score 0):

Both built-in [streams](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) and the [cURL extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) have the ability to make requests through a proxy.  Using either would be vastly preferable to using a socket directly.

The cURL extension expressly mentions proxy authentication, while streams does not expressly mention it, but accepts the proxy as a URI, so you might be able to use the `proto://user:pass@host:port` syntax.  I have not tried, and don't know for sure if that works.

Comment: yeah, i'd like to use directly socket in my program intead of calling curl extensions.
i don't know what to receive, and what to send to authenticate throw the proxy  ...

Comment: You really don't want to use sockets when someone has already done all the hard work for you in creating a library.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean you want to make a HTTP request via a proxy which requires authentication rather than use the authentication method within Squid to validate requests to your webserver.

You just need to set the right values for CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH  CURLOPT_PROXYPORT (usually 3128) and CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE (http)

```
$ch = curl_init();
$opts=array(
   CURLOPT_PROXY="squid.example.com",
   CURLOPT_PROXYPORT=>3128,
   CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE=>CURLPROXY_HTTP,
   CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH=>CURLAUTH_BASIC,
   CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD=>"${username}:${password}",
   CURLOPT_URL=>"http://www.example.com/sompage.html");
curl_setopt_array($opts);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Note that this assumes that the squid is configured for HTTP authentication (rather than session or NTLM based authentication).

You **really** don't want to do this using sockets in PHP.

HTH

C.