# Fsockopen and proxy authentication in PHP

Tags: php, fsockopen

I'm trying to integrate proxy usage (with authentication) into a script that queries whois data.

What I'm trying to do is

1) Connect to the proxy IP and port
2) authenticate a username and password
3) connect to the whois server and send domain details, receiving the request in return.

I have the script working without proxies

```
private function whois($domeinnaam, $whoisrule)
{
    list ($server, $poort, $domein, $vrij) = $whoisrule;
    $domein = str_replace("{domein}", $domeinnaam, $domein);

    $fp = fsockopen($server, $poort);

    if($fp)
    {
        fputs($fp, $domein."\r\n");
        $data = "";
        while(!feof($fp))
        {
            $data .= fread($fp, 1000);
        }

        fclose($fp);
    }
    else
    {
        $data = "error";
    }

    // Cache whois data
    $this->_whoisdata[$domein] = $data;

    return $data;
}
```

But does anyone how I would integrate a proxy server and authentication into this code?

Comment: A proxy usually works in conjunction with a protocol.`HTTP proxy` / `FTP Proxy` and so on. What about your proxy? It looks like to me a `Socks proxy`

Comment: I think my proxy is a HTTP proxy

Comment: As I can see from your code, you aren't making an HTTP request over the socket, you just write a string. If you need to connect to an HTTP proxy you need to use the HTTP protocol

Answer (score 0):

cURL has some handy `CURLOPT_PROXY*` [options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125714/authenticate-throw-squid-proxy-php-socket/3127302#3127302) shows how to use them.

Comment: Why? Is cURL not avaible? You could at least implement it with cURL on your dev machine and see what goes on the wire (e.g. with wireshark). Then you know what to write and read on the socket.